# Exercise books on manifolds

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I am using An Introduction To Manifolds by Loring W. Tu. The book has good exercises but they are not enough and some solutions are missing. I am searching for exercise book that is as close as possible to this textbook and with many exercises on differential forms, maps, homeomorphisms, diffeomorphisms and differentials of maps between manifolds.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it is exactly what you are looking for, and the differences in notation can be confusing, but I have found [Analysis and Algebra on Differentiable Manifolds: A Workbook for Students and Teachers](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Analysis-Algebra-Differentiable-Manifolds-Mathematics/dp/9400759517) by Gadea et al very helpful at times. Might be worth having a look to see if it meets your needs.

Comment: Thank you for your time, will definitely have a look and will inform you if it helps.